# (Accessibility) Change auto focus to other component when using TalkBack

Tags: java, android, android-layout

With the TalkBack setting enabled, the accessibility focus shifts to the hamburger icon automatically. (makes sense since it's the upperleft component in the screen).

When a user opens my app with TalkBack enabled, I want the focus to automatically select the text in the toolbar. This way, the name of the screen is spoken out loud, instead of the drawer action.

I have added an example below:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code below on your toolbar (title) object.

```
android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@id/drawer"
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: Seems like we came up with the same answer, around the same time!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to set the focus manually on another component by simply adding the the following field:

```
android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@id/idOfTheComponentThatHasTheAutoFocus"
```

In this way, you make sure that this component will be called first in the traversal order.